# Load Audio in html with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a list of music I want When I click image of music opened media player with ajax, I Use this code in HTML:

```
 <div class="container ">
     <div class="row center">
        @foreach($singles as $single)
           <div class="col-md-2 folio-thumb">
             <a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-
               Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"><img class="img-responsive"
                src={{asset($single->Single_Image)}} /></a>
                     <h6 style="color:white" id="music">
                      {{$single>Single_Name}}<a href="/"></a></h6>
           </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
   </div>
   <audio id="audio" controls="controls" style="margin-left:150px;">
      <source id="audioSource" src="">
       Your browser does not support the audio format.
   </audio>
```

And Ajax Code:

```
$('.folio-thumb').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var elm = e.target;
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
         source.src = elm.getAttribute('data-value');
          audio.load(); 
         audio.play(); 
   });
```

But I Give this Error in console:

`GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/null net::ERR_ABORTED
home:288 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

Comment: Ok. So, the play requested was interrupted by a new load request. What's the deal?

Comment: My Problem is here that audio don't play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved My problem

```
 @foreach($singles as $single)
       <div class="col-md-2 folio-thumb">
         <a href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-
           Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"><img class="img-responsive"
            src={{asset($single->Single_Image)}} /></a>
                 <h6 style="color:white" id="music">
                  {{$single>Single_Name}}<a href="/"></a></h6>
       </div>
    @endforeach
```

in this code I add data-value to `<a>` But `<img>` tag is True

```
     <a href="#" ><img class="img-responsive"data-
            value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-
           Death_Becomes_Fur.oga"
            src={{asset($single->Single_Image)}} /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using selector `.folio-thumb` even that class in for the wrapping `<div>` – `<div class="col-md-2 folio-thumb">`. Which results `var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');` returning `null`. (The div does not have any data attributes).

You should add selector to the `<a>` element and use that in the JavaScript.

Example;
`<a class="play-button" href="#" data-value="http://media.w3.org/2010/07/bunny/04-Death_Becomes_Fur.oga">...</a>`

```
$('.play-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var elm = e.target;
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
        var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');
         source.src = elm.getAttribute('data-value');
          audio.load(); 
         audio.play(); 
   });
```

Working example at https://jsbin.com/ceqotimuru/edit?html,js,output

Best regards,
Riku

Comment: Check my working example. Do you have some spaces in the video name? e.g. row change in the middle of the name?

Comment: My Script code is between `<script>
        $(document).ready(function () { //My Code});` this can be problem?

Comment: No that does not cause this issue. What error do you get? Still the same `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/null net::ERR_ABORTED` ?

Comment: Yes I Receive this Error

Comment: Did you update the JavaScript and the a element to have the same selector? So a has class e.g. "play-button" and javascript uses $('.play-button') selector? Those two has to match.